# how to assign text to ggplot with a condition when y axis is not numeric in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, conditional-statements, geom-text

I want to annotate a percentage number of missing values for each variable that actually has any missing values somewhere above the corresponding variable blue line.
I can add a text using geom_text but I have difficulty with how to select those vars with Nas. I would appreciate any hint with this.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(naniar)
gg_miss_var(airquality) + labs(y = "Look at all the missing ones")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `naniar::miss_var_summary()` to create a data frame with labels for all variables with at least one `NA`:

```
df <- miss_var_summary(airquality) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(n_miss > 0) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(pct_label = paste0(round(pct_miss, 1), '%'))
```

You can then use this data frame inside your `geom_text()` line:

```
gg_miss_var(airquality) + 
  geom_text(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(variable), y = n_miss, label = pct_label), 
            vjust = 1.5) +
  labs(y = "Look at all the missing ones")
```

[image: lollipop chart with percentages for values larger than zero]